# Reading files in directory ending with digit python

Tags: python, file, directory

I have created the following code. The purpose of this code is to scan through a specified directory, check which files end with a digit and then execute a previous python program I have created which will implement changes on the files ending with a digit.

```
def my_main():



for filenames in os.listdir("dir/"):
    if filenames.endswith("1.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("2.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("3.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("4.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("5.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("6.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("7.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("8.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("9.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')

    elif filenames.endswith("10.txt"):
        execfile('Location of previous python program')
```

I'm looking for help as how I could improve my code, I want it to be cleaner and not as messy, I also want it to be generalised and not just hardwired to work in a certain directory.

Any advice on how I could achieve this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression (from the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module) to match the filename:

```
import re

def name_ends_with_digit(filename):
   return re.match(r'\w*\d+.txt$', filename)

def main():
   for filename in os.listdir("dir/"):
      if name_ends_with_digit(filename):
          execfile('Location of previous python program')
```

The regular expression checks if the string matches the pattern:

1. any number of word character (letter, digit, or underscore)
2. followed by at least one digit
3. followed by '.txt'.
4. followed by nothing else (the `$`)

A simple example below:

```
import re

def name_ends_with_digit(filename):
   return re.match(r'\w*\d+.txt$', filename)

def check(filename):     
    if name_ends_with_digit(filename):
        print 'match'
    else:
        print 'no match'

check('test1.txt')
check('1.txt')
check('10.txt')
check('text1.txtyyy')
check('text.txt')
```

This prints:

```
match
match
match
no match
no match
```

Comment: Thank you, has made my code much clearer now. Just when I go to open the files which do end with a digit, no changes have been made to them.

Comment: I added the output o that fully working example in my answer. I think that does what you expect, so the mistake must be in another part of our program.

Comment: Yes Paul, you're solution did help. Now I must try figure out where my other problem is. Thank you , much appreciated!

Comment: Check the other answer with `glob` as well. Seems shorter :)

Comment: sorry paul was so strung out trying to fix my execfile problem I forgot, thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glob` to find the files you are interested in:

```
from glob import glob

files = glob("/dir/*[0-9].txt"):
```

Also `str.endswith` takes a tuple of arguments so you need one `if` not 10:

```
ends = ( "1.txt","2.txt","3.txt"....)

if filenames.endswith(ends):
         ........
```

If you are only interested in seeing if there is any match use `iglob`:

```
from glob import iglob

if next(iglob("/dir/*[0-9].txt"), None):
    ............
```

`iglob` returns an iterator so if `next(iglob("/dir/*[0-9]*.txt"), None)` does not return the default `None` you know you have at least one match.

Comment: This seems better than mine IMHO. But I think it should match _at least one_ digit, `[0-9]+` to do what the OP asks?

Comment: @paul-g,  it won't match unless there is at least one digit, there was a stray `*`